# xmlbeans 5.1.1 using subdirectories of schema to generate sources in maven

Tags: xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.9.3 with OpenJDK17 and XmlBeans 5.1.1 and it should generate sources from xsd files in the directory ${project.basedir}/src/main/schema. On top of that there are xsd files in a subdirectory of schema (${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/sub). Unfortunally only the sources from the xsd files in the schema directory are generated, but not the ones in the subfolder.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repackage>schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans</repackage>
                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/</sourceDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

How can I include the subdirectory in the source generation?

I tried to add a second line of sourceDir in the condiguration section

```
<sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/</sourceDir>
<sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/sub</sourceDir>
```

which had as result, that only the xsd files in the subdirectory were included in the source generation.

I tried to seperate the pathes with comma and semicolon

${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/;${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/sub/

which didn't work.
Error Message: Set configuration  (='${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/;${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/mcm/') to a valid directory containing *.xsd,*.wsdl files.

My workaround for the time is to change the structure of the project. By creating a child module I can run xmlbeans two times. The child module generates sources from the xsd files in the subfolder with the target directory of the generate-sources folder in the main module.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDir>(mainroot)\src\main\schema\schema  \sub</sourceDir>
                <javaTargetDir>(mainroot)\target\generated-sources</javaTargetDir>
                <classTargetDir>(mainroot)\target\generated-resources</classTargetDir>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

To make it work I have to run `mvn clean` and `mvn package` in two steps. Otherwise the target folder of the main module is deleted after the generated sources from the child are copied (because order is child clean -> child package -> main clean -> main package).